# Update submit button text with value from input field

Tags: jquery

im trying to update the text in my form submit button based on a value of a selected text input box.

```
if (document.getElementById('pay_other').checked) {
   rate_value = document.getElementById('other_amount').value;
}

$('input[id="paymentAmount"]').val(rate_value);
```

using the above i can get the value i need. Example: 100

I now need to change the text of the submit button to **Pay £100 today**.

Ive tried various ways to insert the variable **rate_value** without sucess.

processPayment is the submit button id

```
$("#processPayment").prop('value', 'Pay £'rate_value' today');
```

Comment: `'Pay £' + rate_value + ' today'` , simple string concatenation

Comment: In JS, you join (concatenate) strings together with the plus sign, like `$("#processPayment").prop('value', 'Pay £' + rate_value + ' today');`

Comment: @PranavCBalan thanks! as easy as that!

Answer (score 0):

In JS, you join (concatenate) strings together with the plus sign, like

`$("#processPayment").prop('value', 'Pay £' + rate_value + ' today');`

Answer (score 0):

The question was already answered in the comments of the original post, but I wanted to add that since you apparently have jquery imported, you can simplify your code by using jquery throughout:

```
if ($('#pay_other').is(':checked')) {
   rate_value = $('#other_amount').val();
}

$('#paymentAmount').val(rate_value);

$('#processPayment').prop('value', 'Pay £' + rate_value + ' today');
```